# What steps are taken to create the optical illusion "Autostereograms"?

Tags: images

There are many images in which letters/text appear when you stare hard into them, called [Autostereograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram). I want to know how they are created. This is an example (here's the [hidden image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Stereogram_Tut_Shark_Depthmap.png)):

[image]

I want to create an album cover, so what steps are taken to create such an image myself?

Comment: Uuu I saw a shark! Too bad I'm one of those people who see these images only when I cross my eyes, and I see the images "carved" not "bumped". Good question. +1

Comment: Let me see if I understand your point, you are asking about [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)?

Comment: Steganography is the *more general concept* of embedding hidden images within something else. But yeah. @DiogoRocha

Comment: no not exactly steganography. the aim is to stare hard to see beyond the visible.

Comment: So, take a try on [this site](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/steganography/steganography.php). It is a online steganography generator.

Comment: @DiogoRocha No, that's not what he wants. The "secret" message should be a 3D stereogram visible to the human eye, not a digital watermark. Just like the image in the question — it's a shark if you look closely.

Comment: lol, I looked from all the different angles and saw nothing beyond color points........ I thought Kartik was looking for a way to hide a image inside another... now I understand the point...

Comment: http://www.physics.gla.ac.uk/Optics/play/TIM/index.html http://www.swiftgear.com/stmaker/features.html http://wmi.math.u-szeged.hu/xaos/doku.php?id=documentation:manual:stereogram http://www.aolej.com/stereo http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=stereograph

Comment: @TomWijsman Why did you not post that as a answer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Why should I be copying Google results into answers? [Links only are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) I found these in under a minute, now I wonder "*what problem the OP has with using these*"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've known these previously as [Single Image Random Dot Stereograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_dot_stereogram#Further_development) (SIRDS) or 3D Stereograms and if you are simply looking to create them rather than know the process (which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_dot_stereogram) will helpfully teach you about) then I've found a couple of options.

- [Stereogram Creator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Others/Stereogram-Creator.shtml) is for Windows
- [Easy Stereogram Generator](http://www.easystereogrambuilder.com/3d-stereogram-maker.aspx) is an online generator that will walk you through what is needed and can do it [pretty quickly and easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iPqf.jpg)
- [SIRDS](http://www.katsurashareware.com/pgs/sirds.html) is a MAC OS X solution

Answer (score 3):

The only program that can generate autostereograms I know of is a program called [TIM](http://www.physics.gla.ac.uk/Optics/play/TIM/index.html). It's [java](http://www.physics.gla.ac.uk/Optics/play/TIM/TIM.jar), however I think the colors it uses is fairly ugly. However it is GPL so you may be able to use the source and edit it to a better pallet.